# Property of a PHP Object itself is another Object of another class

Tags: php, class, object

I am pretty sure that we can store reference to an Object's property with an Object of a different class.
But I am stuck with this code. 
The `__construct()` functions of both `metro` and `town` assigns the values for `$name` and `$pop` of those objects . But I need the `__construct()` function of the class `city` to create a new object of either class `metro` or class `town` depending on the value of `$pop` of the object of class `city`

```
<?php

class metro 
{
  public $name;
  public $pop;

  function __construct($name,$pop)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->pop = $pop;
  }
}

class town 
{
  public $name;
  public $pop;

  function __construct($name,$pop)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->pop = $pop;
  }
}

class city 
{
  public $name;
  public $pop;
  public $derived_city;

  function __construct($name,$pop)
   {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->pop = $pop;
    if ($this->pop >= 50)
    {
      $derived_city = new metro($this->name,$this->pop);
    }
    else 
    {
      $derived_city = new town($this->name,$this->pop);
    }
  }
}

$city1 = new city("Bombay",100);
echo $city1->derived_city->pop;
?>
```

Comment: You need to assign `$this->derived_city` instead of `$derived_city`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I got my mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
class metro 
{
  public $name;
  public $pop;

  function __construct($name,$pop)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->pop = $pop;
  }
}

class town 
{
  public $name;
  public $pop;

  function __construct($name,$pop)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->pop = $pop;
  }
}

class city 
{
  public $name;
  public $pop;
  public $derived_city;

  function __construct($name,$pop)
   {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->pop = $pop;
    if ($this->pop >= 50)
    {
      $derived_city = new metro($this->name,$this->pop);
    }
    else 
    {
      $derived_city = new town($this->name,$this->pop);
    }

    $this->derived_city = $derived_city;
  }
}

$city1 = new city("Bombay",100);
print_r($city1->derived_city);
echo $city1->derived_city->pop;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I got my mistake.